# Algorithm to find range of data in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an array

```
$array = [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0];
```

What is the quickest algorithm to group all the 0s and represent them as their starting and ending index?

(ie) Output of this should be (0,5),(10,17)...

Comment: You will find something from this...   http://jsfiddle.net/aQsuP/9/

Comment: @HarshaW: The link you have posted starts by sorting the input array, which will destroy the indices immediately, rendering it unusable for OP's purpose.

Comment: I can't think of anything other than a manual traversal. Should be pretty much as fast as it could be.

Comment: I agree with @dotNET. Better to try manual traversal

Comment: A multi-threaded solution should prove faster. Just split your input array into segments and manually traverse each segment on a different thread. Join the results at the end (which is slightly more complex than simply concatenating the results, but still simple enough).

Comment: They're already grouped... You need to count the consecutive zeros  and reset the count accordingly. Please show what you tried and mention what language

Comment: @dotNet I wouldn't suggest splitting in the middle of a group. You still have to iterate to determine boundaries

Comment: @cricket_007: For larger arrays, doing it on multiple threads will result in hugely reduced time. Shouldn't matter where we split, because we can easily join the result of each thread at the end. Just take the last result of each segment and the first result of next segment; if their indices are consecutive, merge them, else keep them.

Comment: "Larger" array in this case would likely be in hundreds of millions of items. You have the thread start and join overhead to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-code will be something like this -

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     if(array[i] == 0) {
         int left = i;
         while(i + 1 < array.length && array[i + 1] == 0) {
              i++; 
         }
         // print range [left, i] 
     }    
}
```

Time complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is array length. Space complexity is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Let me write multithreaded approach in pseudo-code form:

```
Function ZeroHunter()
  Split the array into N segments (where N is multiple of number of threads available)
  Create a Dictionary<SegmentNumber, Result>. Let's call it DicResults.

  For i = 0 to Number of segments
    Result = ProcessSegmentOnNewThread(S)
    DicResults.Add(i, Result)
  Next

  Wait for all threads to complete

  ConcatResults(DicResults)
End Function
```

Code for ProcessSegmentOnNewThread:

```
Function ProcessSegmentOnNewThread(Segment S)
  Create a new thread

  List<int, int> lst;
  while i < S.Length
    if S[i] == 0 Then 
     NewEntry = lst.Add(i, i)
     while i < S.Length and S[i] == 0
       NewEntry.End++;
       i++
     end while
    end if

    i++
  end while

  Return the results in the form of List<int, int>
End Function
```

Code for ConcatResults():

```
Function ConcatResults(DicResults)
  Sort the input dictionary on segment number (the dictionary key that is)

  For i = 0 to DicResults.Count - 1
    If DicResult[i].End = DicResult[i+1].Start - 1
      Set DicResult[i].End = DicResult[i+1].End
      Remove DicResult[i+1] from the dictionary
    End If
  Next

  Return DicResult
End Function
```

Thing to note is that while this algorithm will beat non-threaded algorithms for very large arrays, you should not use it for smaller arrays because the overhead of creating threads and joining the results will outweigh the potential benefit of threading.

Answer (score 0):

try this buddy...!! hope its fine :D

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[12] = {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0};
int i;
int t = 0;
  for( i = 0; i < (int)( sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])); i++) {
     if(a[i] == t) {
         int k = i;
         while(i + 1 < (int)( sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) && a[i + 1] == 0) {
              i++; 
         }
         printf("range(%d,%d)\n",k,i);
     }    
}
}
```